# RESTful services on Jboss 7 not responding

Tags: web-services, rest, jboss, ejb, resteasy

I got some application in which i try to expose some RESTful webservices.
Unfortunately I'm stuck. Project builds and deploys fine but i just cannot access my services using GET requests.

My war looks alike:
war.

```
war
|--index.html
|--WEB-INF
   |--web.xml
   |--classes
      |--classes here..
```

I got empty `web.xml`:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
</web-app>
```

Application class:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

}
```

And service class:
    import javax.ejb.Stateless;
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

```
@Path("/test")
@Stateless
public class RestTest {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/status")
    public Response getStatus() {
        return Response.ok("{\"status\":\"Service is running...\"}").build();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/status/{param}")
    public Response getStatusParam(@PathParam("param") String param) {
        return Response.ok("{\"status\":\"Service is running...\"," +
                "\"param\":\"" + param + "\"}").build();
    }
}
```

I was trying to access my services by `http://localhost:8080/rest/test/status` but I'm getting 404. If I try `http://localhost:8080/rest` I'm getting my `index.html` so my war should be deployed correctly. There are also no errors while deploying.

I have tried to remove `@Stateless` annotation and return my class in `MyApplication.getClasses()` method but it's not helping. Bean is for sure visible because Jboss logs my it's bindings.

I also removed all jax-rs and restesy jars from my war, to be sure that I'm using right ones (provided by Jboss).

What should I do more to get my services running?

@EDIT

If I deploy war like that it works. What should I do to expose war like that if its included in ear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run your example as you described and service is running, I received   {"status":"Service is running..."}.

Just to make sure that your service is deployed correctly, did you see in the log file when you run the Jboss something like this

[org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: MyApplication

Comment: My bad. If i deploy just war it works. You know what should I do to make it work if war is inside ear? Should I add something in application.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question was a bit wrong but I still would like to post answer. Maybe it will help to some body.

To make it work I had to add few lines to `web.xml`. This is this fragment:

```
<module id="war">
    <web>
        <web-uri>war-1.0.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>/rest</context-root>
    </web>
</module>
```

Then I had to call my services by `http://localhost:8080/rest/rest/test/status` path, so i also edited MyApplication class changing annotation `@ApplicationPath("/rest")` to `@ApplicationPath("/")`, Then everything works fine and services are available under `http://localhost:8080/rest/test/status` path.